# Wget not working as expected

Tags: wget, command-line-arguments

```
wget -nd -a pdf -o drgnchain.pdf https://dragonchain.com/assets/Dragonchain_Business_Summary.pdf
```

I would expect the downloaded PDF to be named `drgnchain.pdf` and be the sole file after executing this command. However, not only does this command unexpectedly get me 2 files, but `drgnchain.pdf` is not a valid PDF either.

I get these 2 PDFs:

[image: screenshot]

I thought `-o` would save the PDF with custom name, but it doesn't seem to be working. What am I missing?

Comment: I think you're confusing wget with curl. Both `-o` and `-a` are about log files, not the data you're downloading. You probably meant `-O` (capital O) where you have `-o` (little oh).

Comment: Oh, that's the answer, lol. I didn't even know flags were case sensitive. I spent 2 hours thinking about this. Thanks!

Comment: @barrycarter Definitely `-O`. Make it your answer and I will upvote it.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I don't believe in the points system. I'm just happy to help people. Feel free to post it yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `-o` and `-a` are [about log files](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Logging-and-Input-File-Options), not the data you're downloading. Option switches are case sensitive. You probably meant [`-O`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Download-Options) where you have `-o`.